# Disable shortvrb in math mode

Tags: math-mode, verbatim

I have enabled `shortvrb` so that I can enclose text in pipes to write small pieces of code. Unfortunately this conflicts with math mode when I write `$|A|$` to indicate the cardinality of a set. How can I disable `shortvrb` in math mode ?

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\everymath{\UndefineShortVerb{\|}\vert}

\begin{document}

$|A|$     

\end{document}
```

However, it has a problem with footnotes. The reason why the following make more sense:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\begin{document}

$\vert A\vert$     

\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately the first form interacts in funky ways with other parts of the document :( (not footnotes, actually)

Comment: However the `\DefineShortVerb` and `\UndefineShortVerb` couple is still very useful, I can enable the macro only in those sections where I really need it and keep it disabled otherwise.

Comment: @NoWhereMan: You can use `\DefineShortVerb` and `\UndefinedShortVerb` wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\makeatletter
\edef|{\unexpanded{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi{\vert}}{\unexpanded\expandafter{|}}}
\makeatother
```

but of course you won't be able to use `\UndefineShortVerb` and `\DefineShortVerb` again.

It's best to resort to `\vert` or, even better, to `\lvert` and `\rvert| provided by`amsmath`, when a bar in math mode is needed.