# fancyvrb ShortVerb and tikz incompatibity

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, fancyvrb

I've been working on a document that has a lot of little verbatim bits so I'm using `fancyvrb` `\DeflneShortVerb{\|}`. Now I want to add a tikz picture, and the whole thing fails. It there a simple way around this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (E) {Foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex:
673: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.673 ...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}
```

The following question: [Disable shortvrb in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38463/2693) discusses disabling `\ShortVerb` in math mode, but the solutions there won't work for this case.

Comment: PGF uses `||` for the `or` operator and this produces the error.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I understand the source of the error, I'm wondering if there's a way around it short of (i) using a different short verb escape or (ii) including the image with `\includegraphics` (If there's no solution I'll just do the latter, most likely.)

Comment: Your problem arrives because you use `\DefineShortVerb{\|}` before the call to TikZ. After it's your problem to know what character to use for the verbatim form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I always did like that but it's not a reason for this is the right method : `\AtBeginDocument{\DefineShortVerb{\|}}` but it's enough to place `\DefineShortVerb{\|}` after `\usepackage{tikz}`

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,shortvrb} 
% possible is  \AtBeginDocument{\MakeShortVerb{\|}}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\begin{document}
And we can |_change_| the character before the picture.

\SaveVerb{Verb}|_OK_!_verbatim_material_!|

\begin{tikzpicture}\node at (1,0) [rectangle,draw,red,fill=yellow!25]{\UseVerb{Verb}};
\node at (1,1.1) [circle,draw,fill=blue!15] {$\|A\| \leq \epsilon$};
\end{tikzpicture} 

And we can still |_change_| the character after the picture.   

\tikz \draw (0,0) -| (2,2); 

\pgfmathparse{0||0} \verb+ \pgfmathparse{0||0} + 0 or 0 : \pgfmathresult

\pgfmathparse{0||1}  \verb+ \pgfmathparse{0||1} + 0 or 1 :  \pgfmathresult

\pgfmathparse{1||1} \verb+ \pgfmathparse{1||1} + 1 or 1 : \pgfmathresult 

\end{document}
```

I work with pgf 2.1 cvs but I think I always used \AtBeginDocument{\MakeShortVerb{\|}}.

[image]

Comment: @AlanMunn My solution is correct with pgf 2.1 cvs but with pgf 2.1 percusse's answer is fine. Perhaps you need to accept percusse's answer. The cvs version is not current version.

Comment: Are you sure? I can run your example with pgf 2.1 with no problem.

Comment: My example yes! but `\tikz{\node {|A|};}` gives an error with pgf 2.1 and not with pgf 2.1 cvs. You can load tikz without an error but a problem appears if you try to use `|` inside a tikz environment.

Comment: If you don't need verbatim text inside a node you can use my solution with pgf 2.1.

Answer (score 12):

I have put the undefine command at the beginning of each picture and reenabled after the picture. It looks like a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\tikzset{execute at begin picture={\UndefineShortVerb{\|}},
         execute at end   picture={\DefineShortVerb{\|}}}
\begin{document}
And we can |_change_| the character before the picture.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] {$\|A\| \leq \epsilon$};
\end{tikzpicture}

And we can still |_change_| the character after the picture.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not sure if it's robust though.

---

**EDIT** After reading the comments, I realized that the example above is a little bit cheating so I tried an example without `\|` but standalone `|` pair and it broke down. To fix that we need to really force the introduction of the "un"definition go all the way up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\tikzset{every picture/.prefix code={\UndefineShortVerb{\|}},
         execute at end picture={\DefineShortVerb{\|}}}

\begin{document}
We can |_&$change#$\_| the character before the picture.
\tikz[baseline=-0.35em]{ \node { |A|} ; }
And we can still |change| the character after the picture. I didn't know that 
pipe pair is rendered as an emdash-like seperator.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] {|A|};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course `|foo|` will not be verbatim inside a `tikzpicture`, but I don't think this will be a problem.

Comment: Beautiful.  Thanks, I hoped there was a solution like this.  So many little bits of TikZ to know about... (@egreg No, I have no need for verbatim in the picture).

Comment: With `\DefineShortVerb{\|}` after `\usepackage{tikz}`it's not useful to use `execute at begin picture etc.`or perhaps I don't see a subtlety.

Comment: If you want to avoid emdash character, you can use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: http://texblog.net/latex-archive/fonts/symbols/ is useful about special characters

Comment: Finally I don't understand why you use `\ UndefineShortVerb{\|}` ?

Comment: @Altermundus You can try to write `|A|` in a node while it is enabled. If you don't turn it off. It will give an error if `fancyvrb` is in action in my example.

Comment: @percusse Ok I found the problem. My solution works because I work with pgf 2.1 cvs. Your answer is fine with pgf 2.1

Answer (score 7):

The problem can be dealt with in a more fundamental way. I include here some of my old patches to **fancyvrb** package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  every begin picture/.style={every picture/.prefix code={#1}},
  every end picture/.style={execute at end picture={#1}},
  every begin picture={\FV@am@undefineshortverb},
  % 'every picture' is set in the tikz scope. Hence the following is redundant:
  % every end picture={\FV@am@defineshortverb}
}
\def\FV@am@defineshortverb{}
\def\FV@am@undefineshortverb{}
\def\FV@am@swap#1#2{#2#1}
\def\FV@am@csname#1#2{%
  \expandafter\FV@am@swap\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{#1}%
}
\def\DefineShortVerb{\FV@Command{}{DefineShortVerb}}
\def\FVC@DefineShortVerb#1{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\@car\string#1x\@nil}%
  \ifx\reserved@a\@backslashchar
    \ifcsname FV@CC@\string#1\endcsname
      \FV@Error{`\expandafter\@gobble\string#1' is already a short
        verb character}\FV@eha
    \fi
  \else
    \FV@Error{Token `\detokenize{#1}' isn't escaped}\FV@eha
  \fi
  \FVC@@DefineShortVerb#1%
}
\def\FVC@@DefineShortVerb#1{%
  \begingroup
  \lccode`\~=`#1%
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def\reserved@a{\edef~}\let\reserved@b~%
  }%
  \FV@am@csname\let{FV@AC@\string#1}\reserved@b
  \FV@am@csname\edef{FV@CC@\string#1}{\the\catcode`#1}%
  \FV@am@csname\let{FV@KV@\string#1}\FV@KeyValues
  \reserved@a{%
    \let\noexpand\FV@KeyValues
    \FV@am@csname\noexpand{FV@KV@\string#1}%
    \noexpand\FVC@Verb\expandafter\@gobble\string#1%
  }%
  \g@addto@macro\dospecials{\do#1}%
  \g@addto@macro\@sanitize{\@makeother#1}%
  \g@addto@macro\FV@am@defineshortverb{\DefineShortVerb#1}%
  \g@addto@macro\FV@am@undefineshortverb{\UndefineShortVerb#1}%
  \catcode`#1=\active
}
\def\UndefineShortVerb#1{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\@car\string#1x\@nil}%
  \ifx\reserved@a\@backslashchar
    \ifcsname FV@CC@\string#1\endcsname\else
      \FV@Error{`\expandafter\@gobble\string#1' is not a short
        verb character}\FV@eha
    \fi
  \else
    \FV@Error{Token `\detokenize{#1}' isn't escaped.}\FV@eha
  \fi
  \FV@UndefineShortVerb#1%
}
\def\FV@UndefineShortVerb#1{%
  \catcode`#1=\csname FV@CC@\string#1\endcsname\relax
  \FV@am@csname\let{FV@CC@\string#1}\relax
  \begingroup
  \lccode`\~=`#1%
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def\reserved@a{\let~}}%
  \begingroup
  \FV@am@csname{\endgroup\reserved@a}{FV@AC@\string#1}%
  \FV@am@stackdeplete{\do#1}\dospecials
  \FV@am@stackdeplete{\@makeother#1}\@sanitize
  \FV@am@stackdeplete{\DefineShortVerb#1}\FV@am@defineshortverb
  \FV@am@stackdeplete{\UndefineShortVerb#1}\FV@am@undefineshortverb
}
% I introduced the macro \FV@am@stackdeplete because I saw a possible
% failure edge case with the scheme in fancyvrb about stack depletion
% (not popping).
\def\FV@am@stackdeplete#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\remove@a##1\FV@nil{##1}%
  \def\remove@b##1\FV@nil{}%
  \def\remove@c##1#1##2\FV@nil##3\FV@nil##4\FV@nnil{%
    \expandafter\endgroup##3\def#2{##1##2}\FV@nil
  }%
  \expandafter\remove@c#2\FV@nil\remove@a\FV@nil
    #1\FV@nil\remove@b\FV@nil\FV@nnil
}
\makeatother

\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\begin{document}
And we can |_change_$%#| the character before the picture.

\SaveVerb{Verb}|#%_OK_$_and_£_!#_verbatim_material|

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (1,0) [rectangle,draw,red,fill=yellow!25]{\UseVerb{Verb}};
\node at (1,1.4) [circle,draw,fill=blue!15] {|A| $\|A\| \leq \epsilon$};
\end{tikzpicture}

And we can still |$%#_change_| the character after the picture.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case, you don't need to define something with `execute at begin picture`.