# TikZ messes up spacing of fancyvrb environments

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, verbatim, fancyvrb

I'm trying to use environments saved with `SaveVerbatim` of `fancyvrb` in TikZ nodes.  But TikZ seems to mess up the spacing in a way that I can't use this for code snippets.  The following MWE shows how the second line isn't aligned properly with respect to the first line and how TikZ adds an empty line at the top of the node.  How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{SaveVerbatim}{foo}
def foo():
    return 42
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\UseVerbatim{foo}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=3cm,inner sep=0,draw] {\UseVerbatim{foo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: Looks like some more effort is needed. See e.g. the answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60060/245790

Comment: @MS-SPO I don't think this has to do with `\ShortVerb`.

Comment: According to source2e.pdf, `verbatim` is a trivlist and adds `\topsep` at the top and bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\BUseVerbatim` is better for this application.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{foo}
def foo():
    return 42
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\UseVerbatim{foo}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0,draw] {\BUseVerbatim{foo}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=\fboxsep,draw] {\BUseVerbatim{foo}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to do the trick.  Although I find it a bit messy.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{SaveVerbatim}{foo}
def foo():
    return 42
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\newsavebox{\baz}
\sbox{\baz}{\begin{minipage}{3cm}\UseVerbatim{foo}\end{minipage}}

\UseVerbatim{foo}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=3cm,inner sep=0,draw] {\usebox{\baz}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:  Note that the savebox width = `\hsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\foo}

\begin{document}

\setbox\foo=\vbox{\topsep=0pt
\begin{verbatim}
def foo():
    return 42
\end{verbatim}}

\hrule\noindent\usebox\foo\hrule

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=3cm, inner sep=0, draw] {\usebox\foo};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```